# how to detect peaks in a particular range?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency

I have a plot between 0-2000 Hz. I want to find peaks between 0-135 Hz only. 
I am using `findpeaks` to detect the peaks but there is no way to extract the peaks within a particular limit.
Can somebody suggest any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexing to restrict your data vector. For example:

```
f = linspace(0,2000,10000); %// assumed frequency values
y = rand(size(f)); %// example y values. Sames size as frequency vector

ind = f>=0 & f<= 135; %// logical index to select desired range
[peaks, locs] = findpeaks(y(ind));
```

Comment: @user3217416 Please upvote your selected answer as well.

Comment: @kkuilla I am still short of the required reputation to vote for answers